# defining conjugate diameters

Tags: geometry

I was asked the following question:

> "Prove analytically Proposition VII-12 that in any ellipse the sum of the squares on any two of its conjugate diamters is equal tot the sum of the squares on it's two axes."

What are conjugate diameters? Are they diameters that make right angles with each other?

Comment: Conjugate diameters are line segments that go through the center of the ellipse and are perpendicular to each other. The two axes are a special case of conjugate diameters.

Comment: See Wikipedia's ["Conjugate diameters" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_diameters#Of_ellipse): *"For an ellipse, two diameters are conjugate if and only if the tangent line to the ellipse at an endpoint of one diameter is parallel to the other diameter."* Ie, conjugate-ness isn't a property of each being *perpendicular* to the other, but of each being *parallel* to the associated tangent lines of the other. (For a circle, this amounts to the same thing.) There's also a characterization in terms of each diameter bisecting all chords parallel to the other.

Comment: @Xaver after further consideration, I don't think that is true.

Comment: Yes, I after creating a GeoGebra example, I saw that the definition given by me was wrong. The definition given by Blue is correct. For a visualization, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, *Blue* already mentioned the definition from Wikipedia. To illustrate things, I created a GeoGebra file. You can download it [here](https://filebin.net/vvngio7ho290s0ri/Ellipsis.ggb?t=p6d2m11r). Save the file with a `.ggb` extension and open it with GeoGebra.